# UIAlertController changes my button colors

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I call a `UIAlertController` like this:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title"
                                                                         message:@"msg"
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Accept" 
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {/*...*/}
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel 
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {/*...*/}];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My problem is that when the `UIAlertController` is shown, it changes the color of my navigation bar from yellow to white and the system's light info button from blue to gray (it doesn't look wrong, it rather looks like a wanted "make the screen look less colorful" effect). If the user presses the home button at that moment, the app will keep that colors when the the app enters from background again (which takes the user to the login screen, which has the white/gray colors).

Is there a workaround to that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iOS7, view has been provided with a different behavior when displaying alert view:

> When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the
>   tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a
>   custom view subclass that uses tintColor in its rendering should
>   override tintColorDidChange to refresh the rendering when appropriate.

As written you should override the `tintColorDidChange`, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443182/check-if-tintcolor-is-dimmed-in-tintcolordidchange)

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional and happens when any alert is presented. It is because the interactive parts (e.g. the buttons) of your views are not interactive while the alert is presented.

The `tintAdjustmentMode` of the view underneath will have been changed to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` while the alert is presented. You can implement `tintColorDidChange` to respond to this change, but in my opinion you shouldn't.

Comment: Well, mainly I have a problem because there is a case, if the user has activated a "high security" setting, that the Window is changed and the `UIAlertController` is never closed. Do you know of a nice way to close all `UIAlertControler`s?

Comment: No, but off the top of my head, they will be available as the `presentedViewController` of whatever VC is showing them